# delete all files in sub folder CSOM

Tags: client-object-model

how  to delete all files in  subfolder in office 365 using CSOM C#.
I have code like particular file only but I need delete all files at a time.

Comment: Well if you know how to delete one file, you can get all files in a folder and iterate over them and delete the files one by one.

Answer (score 2):

@yannisgu is correct to state that @mvp should know how to do this for several files. But this might not be the case, as @mvp might know about the [Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyserverrelativeurl%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which is specifically designed to retrieve one single file, and does not immediately show any alternative approach to get several files.

One alternative way to get all the files of a subfolder for deletion is to go through `RootFolder`, like this:

```
var files =
clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLib").
    RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("TestFolder").Files;
clientContext.Load(files);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

files.ToList().ForEach(file => file.DeleteObject());
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Or you could delete the whole folder in one single move:

```
clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLib").
    RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("TestFolder").DeleteObject();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Update**: If you delete the whole folder you will loose custom permissions, deleting all files is most likely a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most simple way would be to remove the Folder that contains the Files. In the below example [Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyserverrelativeurl%28v=office.15%29.ASPX) is used to return the folder object located at the specified server-relative URL:

```
public static void DeleteFolder(Web web,string folderRelativeUrl)
{
     var folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderRelativeUrl);
     folder.DeleteObject();
     web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

However if you need to preserve Folder, then you could retrieve Files from Folder using [Folder.Files property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.files%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and delete them:

```
    public static void DeleteFiles(string url, SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials,string  folderRelativeUrl)
    {  
        using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            context.Credentials = credentials;
            var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderRelativeUrl);
            context.Load(folder.Files);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            folder.Files.ToList().ForEach(file => file.DeleteObject());
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Downside is that even if you recreate the folder, you may loose broken inheritance and special permissions

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, but I'll leave mine to show alternatives. Also, can you really initialize ClientContext like that for 365? (I will up when you altered according to Robert :) )

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, appreciate it. @eirikb, you're right, to access O365, credentials should be provided as demonstrated in the second example.

Comment: Nice, but just wondering, if you were deploying an autohosted app wouldn't the initialization be different from your second example?

Comment: That's right, for autohosted app it would be different

Comment: I was trying to point out: Why include initialization of `ClientContext` when there are so many different way to initialize it. Oh well. I'll give you the vote I promised now :)

Comment: Thanks, since your answer is correct I cant ignore it too (+1) ;)

Comment: Regarding ClientContext, I prefer to pass Client Object(see the updated example for DeleteFolder method) since as you already mentioned the initialization of ClientContext could vary depending on the app type

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` to load the subfolder and then use `DeleteObject()`.

*Example*:

```
string LibraryName = "Documents";
string siteUrl = "https://YourSite.com/sites/Demo";

SecureString Password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "YourPassword")
{
     Password.AppendChar(c); 
}

using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("YourUserName",Password)
}


var folder = rootWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared%20Documents/MainFolder/SubFolder1/SubFolder2");
ctx.Load(folder);
folder.DeleteObject();

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```